# Set default fetch strategy to LAZY for entity ( XML)?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have an entity defined in my XML persistence file as shown below.  The entity/table in question has over 100 fields, but I only need a handful.  Rather than marking all the fields I don't need with a fetch="LAZY" attribute, can I make the default fetch strategy for all columns for this table be LAZY and only mark the ones I need as fetch="EAGER" ?

I looked thru the Open JPA documentation [here](http://here), but I did not see any reference to this.  Is this possible in the XML entity-mappings?

```
<entity class="Users">
        <table schema="dbo" name="Users"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="Id" column-definition="nchar" length="18"/>
            </id>
            <basic name="about" fetch="LAZY">
                <column name="About" column-definition="nvarchar" length="1000"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="accountId">
                <column name="AccountId" column-definition="nchar" length="18"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="alias">
                <column name="Alias" column-definition="nvarchar" nullable="false" length="8"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="auditCounter">
                <column name="AuditCounter"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="auditPercent">
                <column name="AuditPercentc"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="auditTarget">
                <column name="Audit"/>
            </basic>
            <basic name="CenterId">
                <column name="CenterId" column-definition="nchar" length="18"/>
            </basic>
       </attributes>
    </entity>
```

Comment: Fetching is working with relations only not fields of entity it self, so if you have a relation with another entity you can fetch it lazy, but i don't think you can do this for entity fields

Comment: @mibrahim.iti, it is possible to provide a hint for JPA to lazy fetch basic persistent fields using `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` (or `<basic fetch="LAZY>`, as shown in the question). That being said, there is no standard attribute that would allow to override the fetch mode for all entity fields at once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an entity graph is what you're after.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm

What the above link implies is that you could mark the fields you need to be fetched eagerly, then use an empty load graph with your queries.

Or, you could use a fetch graph, explicitly listing the properties you're interested in, to control the fetch mode on a per-query basis.

The confusing part about the entity graph specification is that basic fields need to be explicitly marked as eagerly fetched as well, despite that (as far as annotation-based configuration goes, at least), the default value for `Basic.fetch` property is already `FetchMode.EAGER`. I have no idea what the behavior will be with XML-based configuration, so I suggest you go with the fetch graph approach and make sure it actually works.